# Can you change your program name listed in volume mixer/sndvol in windows without using Core Audio APIs?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, openal-soft

I have been searching for a way to change the name displayed in the Windows volume mixer/sndvol used in Win 7 preferably that would work with Vista as well.
This might not be such an issue if I was not using OpenAL-Soft to create my sounds.  The only references I seem to come up with are directed to the Windows Core Audio API.  I am trying to not use any more OS specific APIs than I have to so I can more easily port my finished program to Linux later if I wish without having to basically just rewrite my whole program.

Right now my program shows in the mixer, but has the ".exe" attached to it, which I think looks unprofessional. I found [this article on MSDN regarding the CA API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but seems to be more suited to if you are going to access the Windows APIs yourself, and so far my attempts to just use `IAudioSessionControl::SetDisplayName` didn't change anything, since I basically just tried to use only that.

I would prefer to not have to add more than a 10-15 lines of code to just do this, and appears for me to use this API I will be looking at a lot more lines of code. Is there a way I can change the display name my program appears as in Windows volume mixer?

Answer (score 0):

The name in volume mixer is same as window title, so you can just change your window title.

I've tried that, it worked.